# Selenium typekeys issue

Tags: selenium

I am using typekeys to type something and to enable a button in my application.
But whenever the typekeys command is executed in firefox help of the firefox gets opened.

Please, can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Selenium TypeKeys and Type commands work at the browser level so if you are override somethings it won't work in Selenium.

[This bug](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-385)  is still open on the Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the WebDriver API available in Selenium 2.0 (alpha 1) and the `sendKeys` command. Available here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list